# Converting old car clock, to alkaline power

Tags: batteries, circuit-design

I have a clock from an old car, I want to hook it up to a series of alkaline batteries. Will that work, or the batteries do not provide enough current (amps)??

Thank you

Comment: What is special about this clock that makes it something you want to reuse in another mode? You can find all manner of stick on LED clocks that even have date and time on Amazon and eBay for a very small price. These clocks operate on a coin cell battery that typically last several years.

Comment: Last I checked, alkaline batteries were pretty cheap.... hook it up to 8 in series and see. If it does not run long enough... hook in another 8 in parallel to the first 8. Or buy a 12V DC wallwart.

Comment: i can't imagine a clock would need more amps than batteries provide. it just tells the time right? that should use ma at most.

Answer (score 1):

The question (edited) is: "Will that work, or the batteries do not provide enough current (amps)??"

One can't answer this question precisely if is unknown how much current this clock uses. If it is a clock that is connected all the time to car's battery, it should not draw so much current (else it would drain to much from the car's battery when the engine is turned off and the battery is not beeing recharged).

Some old car clocks have two distinct power circuits, one is for keeping time information, and another is for light up a display when the car electric circuit is on. My father had a car in 1983 that had a digital clock at the ceiling, just above the windshield, that used a (beautiful) blue fluorescent display when the power was on; else the display would be off.

If your clock is like this, and you want the display always on, maybe its power requirements will be too high to the batteries.

There's only way for know it for sure: try it. Connect the clock to a 12v source (8 batteries, or even a wall plug) and measure the current.